# MMP for surfaces over a curve where the geometric generic fiber is a rational curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am looking for an explaination or an reference for the following fact:

> Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Z$ be a contraction from a smooth surface $X$ to a curve $Z$. Assume that the geometric generic fiber of $\pi$ is a rational curve. Then we may run a $K_X$-MMP over $Z$ and reach a minimal ruled surface $\pi^\prime:X^\prime \rightarrow Z$.

Comment: Isn't "running MMP" a bit overkill for surfaces? Is this not just something you can find in any introductory text on surfaces (e.g. Beauville, Prop. II.16 and Thm. III.10)? Or are you looking for a more specific construction?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Sorry I have little knowledge about the surface MMP.  In other to use [Beauville, Thm. III.10], one needs to show that $X$ is birational to $Z\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $Z$ is irrational. I tried to use  [Beauville, Corollary. VI.18] and conclude that $X$ is ruled, i.e., $X$ is birational to $C\times\mathbb{P}^1$ where $C$ is some smooth curve. But I'm not sure how to show that $C$ is birational to $Z$ and how to rule out the case that $C=\mathbb{P}^1$